# Fetch parent child relation with level from the same table

Tags: python, django, parent-child, table-relationships, self-referencing-table

Hi I'm new with django and python.

```
# function for fecthing the child
def get_childern(request, username):
    Q = list(Profile.objects.filter(sponsor_id__exact=username))
    populate(request, Q, username)


# Iterate the Queryset 
def populate(request, quesryset, username):
    if quesryset:
        messages.success(request, username+' has '+str(len(quesryset))+' child')
        messages.info(request, quesryset)
        for user in quesryset:
            get_childern(request, user.user_id)
    else:
        messages.warning(request, 'User '+username+' has no child')
        return False

# calling all children 
get_childern(request, username)
```

and I want to add the level, how to break it down further.

Please help me, invest lots of time and mind.
Thanks to all :)

Comment: if anyone wants to give some feedback or idea for a better solution, comment here. Appreciate to all :)

Comment: If you have a solution you must publish it in the section of an answer.

Comment: Thanks @eyllanesc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution if anyone wants to give some feedback or idea for a better solution, comment here. Appreciate to all :)

```
# for return a child query-set
def get_childern(request, username):
    Q = Profile.objects.filter(sponsor_id__exact=username)
    return Q


level = int(1) # set according to need 
tree_set = {}


# iterate the queryset and call itself
# recursion - set the level to control 
def iterate_object(request, quesryset):
    global tree_set
    outer_count = int(0)
    inner_count = int(0)
    level_tree = []
    for users in quesryset:
        outer_count = outer_count + 1
        # messages.info(request, users.user_id)
        Qs = get_childern(request, users.user_id)
        if Qs:
            for child in Qs:
                inner_count = inner_count + 1
                level_tree.append(child)

            # count = count + len(Qs)
            # messages.warning(request, Qs)
        else:
            # messages.warning(request, 'No child')
            pass
    else:
        # messages.error(request, 'Total child at level 2 => ' + str(count))
        # messages.info(request, outer_count)
        # messages.success(request, inner_count)
        global level
        level = level + 1
        # set the numeric value to control the level
        if level <= 10: 
            tree_set.update({level: level_tree})
            iterate_object(request, level_tree)
            return tree_set
        else:
            # messages.warning(request, 'else part')
            pass
```

Comment: I'm working on this functionality, once it has done, I'll update the code and as well explanation.